# changing forms in designer-workflow

Tags: designer-workflow

I want to use 3 or maybe 4 different Infopath forms in my workflow and in each approve step my form will change for example the first approver will see the first form and the second approver will see the second form and etc.

I've no idea how can i do this!

Answer (score 0):

Regularly in any Workflow solution can only be 3 types forms (irellevant of ASPX or InfoPath) - these are Association, Initiation and Modifications.

- In your case you could either use multiple TASKS for each of the
  approval stages. What I mean is basically to have different Task
  Processes (if SharePoint Designer Workflow are used) which leads to
  different Task content types and appropiate forms. -this however
  requires a more complex structure of the workflow and knowledge to do
  it.
- One other alternative is use InfoPath VIEWS in the same InfoPath form
  and and put conditions to use one or the other according to the
  stages where you are (some examples here
  http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/infopath-help/design-a-form-to-respond-to-a-workflow-status-HA010204141.aspx#BM6
  or
  http://workflowexperience.blogspot.ch/2010/07/how-to-create-multi-view-web-based.html)